# In Excel, Lookup function implementation on set of Lookup values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, lookup, vlookup

I'm new to excel lookup function. I have a requirement , can someone guide me on how to implement this using excel lookup.
[inputFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mykHx.png)

In excel sheet , I have items (Book, hat etc) in Column C. In Column D,  I have prices corresponding to items. The item in Column C can be repeated.

So all I want to do is , in new column (for example F), I want to list the items from Column C  (repeated items in column C should be ignored) and in Column F , I need the sum of prices of an item (Which includes repeated item).

**For input please refer "input.png" and for expected output please refer "expected.png"**[expected.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ9ve.png)

If there is any function in excel other than lookup , even that is fine.

Please guide me.

Comment: The WorksheetFunction SumIf will work nicely. Reference: [Excel Magic Trick #13: SUM or COUNT only certain items! SUMIF COUNTIF functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Md9UefuOFAQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could go like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim itemsRng As Range

    With Worksheets("Items") '<-- change "Comparisons" to your actual sheet name
        Set itemsRng = .Range("C5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        With .Range("F5").Resize(itemsRng.Rows.Count)
            .Value = itemsRng.Value
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
        End With
        With .Range("F5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(" & itemsRng.Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ",RC[-1]," & itemsRng.Offset(, 1).Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ")"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @toLearn, did you get through it?

Answer (score 2):

Paste column C in column F and remove duplicates ... check this link [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2)

Then use sumif in column G.... check this link for SUMIF [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

you will get the output you are seeking.